# Loop through txt file comma-separated and use as variable

Tags: bash

I have txt file separated by comma:

```
2012,wp_fronins.pdf
2013,test789.pdf
2014,ok09report.pdf
```

I'm trying to extract from the file each value and pass him to CURL command with a condition before.
For example:

```
if $value1=2012 do 
curl "https://onlinesap.org/reports/$valu1/$value2
```

Any idea ?

Comment: see this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1521462/looping-through-the-content-of-a-file-in-bash

Comment: Are the numbers (2013, 2014, etc.) unique within the file?

Comment: No, they are not unique but repetitive. but the name of the pdf files is unique.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another way to achieve is to read the file directly and cut the rows to get the elements directly.

```
while read p; do
    value1=`echo $p | cut -d',' -f1`
    value2=`echo $p | cut -d',' -f2`
    if [ $value1 = "2012" ]; then
        curl "https://onlinesap.org/reports/$value1/$value2"
    fi
    # Add More conditional statements here for other value1
done < filename.txt
```

Comment: I guess this answer is better than mine

Comment: or `while IFS=, read value1 value2; do` to avoid two sub shell calls and cut, however bash read is slow

Comment: note that quotes are useless around `2012` but should be used around `$value1`, regarding word splitting, with single square bracket `[` otherwise double square bracket could be used

Answer (score 0):

Since the name of the pdf file (value2) is unique, you may try something like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

FILENAME=myFile.txt

cat $FILENAME | awk -F',' '{print $2}' | while read value2; do
  value1=`grep -w "$value2" $FILENAME | awk -F',' '{print $1}'` # watch the back-tick
  if [ $value1 = "2012" ]; then
    curl https://onlinesap.org/reports/$value1/$value2
  fi
done
```

Please notice that the whole file is scanned a second time for each line found.
In other words, its complexity is O(n^2)

Comment: I think I have some problem with spaces in value2. The pdf reports sometimes contain spaces and then the script fails..

Comment: Put the `value2` within quotes when searching `value1`. I updated the answer